# increasing a div width on dragging is not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some `div`. i want adjust `div` width on dragging

My problem is

1. When i use draggable div id in script only one div work properly
2. If i use the common class all div are adjustable when drag a single one
   how can solve this?

```js
$(function () {
  var container = $('.middletablediv'),
      base = $('#timebase1'),
      handle = $('#handle');

  handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    isResizing = true;
    lastDownX = e.clientX;
  });

  $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing)
      return;

    var p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left);

    base.css('width', p);

  }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false;
  });

})
```

```css
.activelevel1 {
  background-color: #EA623E;
}

.timescalebase {
  margin-top: 13px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
}

#handle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8px;
  cursor: w-resize;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
  <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div id="handle" ></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div id="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase3" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div id="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase4" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div id="handle"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `handle` as a common class to make multiple sliders you need to get the parent element (ie `timescalebase`) of the `handle` and use that as `base`.

You can do this by using jQuery's [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method in the handle's `mousedown` handler

```
  handle.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
```

Demo

```js
$(function() {
  var container = $('.middletablediv'),
      base = null,
      handle = $('.handle'),
      isResizing = false;

  handle.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
    isResizing = true;
    lastDownX = e.clientX;
  });

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing)
      return;

    var p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left);

    base.css('width', p);

  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false;

  });
})
```

```css
.activelevel1 {
  background-color: #EA623E;
}
.timescalebase {
  margin-top: 13px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8px;
  cursor: w-resize;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
  <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase3" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timebase4" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
```